# How do I get UI to update in loop with delay?

Tags: swift, delay

I'm writing a cricket simulator app. I want to implement a quick inning in a loop, until the team is all out. But I want a small delay after each ball so users can see the scoreboard updating.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
        while (match.currentInnings == currentInnings)
        {
            playSingleBall()
            if (gameover == true)
            {
                return
            }
            // Here's where I want the delay
       }
```

playSingleBall does a ton of stuff including a lot of computation and then writing to lots of Labels in the view. However, if I put a delay where the comment is (usleep or something else), the labels don't update at all. Can you suggest anything that would make the labels update? Or a delay method that wouldn't have this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Never call sleep on the main thread.  You'll just freeze your UI.  Instead, I suggest using a repeating timer to update your value and then call timer.invalidate when it's time to stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Timer` class, with a repeating handler:

```
// Every 20 sceonds
let interval: TimeInterval = 20

Timer(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    // Do what every you want to do (update the UI)

    // Stop the loop when the game is over
    if (gameover) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously, use `[weak self]` capture list so your timer can't cause view controller from being retained after it's already dismissed. And you should save reference to the timer and the view controller's `deinit` should also `invalidate` it.

Comment: So, I can have the interval at .1s and then the UI will update? I'll give it try.

Comment: @Lankybrit - If you want to update your UI with the optimal frequency, you should consider `CADisplayLink` instead of a `Timer`. It's a special type of timer coordinated with the screen refresh rate. [This is demonstrating a very different animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44008372/1271826), but it illustrates the use of a `CADisplayLink`.

Comment: I'm not an experienced swift programming. I'm using the cricket simulator to learn. So, what does '(timer) in' do? I also forgot to mention that this code is inside of a a button action function, if that has any bearing. Thanks.

Comment: @Lankybrit the block inside the handler is the code which will be executed every x seconds. It’s actually a function (callback) which takes a timer as an input (being called with the timer as an argument, so that we can access it). The timer makes sure that the function is being called with itself as a parameter every x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would put playSingleBall inside an if statement controlled by another variable. This variable would be set to false at the very first line of playSingleBall, and would then be switched back to true whenever one of the logic flows of playSingledBall reaches it's end.

I'd also look at assigning playSingleBall to the mainqueue since it updates the UI.

Something like so:

```
var singleBallBlocker : Bool = true

func playSingleBall() {

   singleBallBlocker = false


   // run the method...

   // at some point.. wherever the function ends or returns you need to call:

   singleBallBlocker = true

}
```

And your code above wherever you might be using it:

```
while (match.currentInnings == currentInnings)
        {
            if singleBallBlocker 
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                   playSingleBall()
                }
            }
            if (gameover == true)
            {
                return
            }
            // Here's where I want the delay
       }
```

Of course if you dont need the blocker to be reset inside the method, then just have it reset wherever you see fit.

Comment: So, I can put the delay where the comment is and then the playSingleBall will be executed asynchronously?

Comment: The problem with the delay here is you can't be sure of how long your playSingleBall method will take. Unless you add extra methods to monitor this, it's kind of like shooting blindly. The advantage of the resetting blocker is that it cant be changed from outside of the while loop. For example, in response of another class or method that represents other elements of your game instance.

Comment: However, youre updating the UI with playSingleBall, all methods that do so should be on the main thread. You can look up how assign simple calculation methods to other async threads like here: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f

Comment: I changed the code as suggested. But when I clicked on 'Quick Inning' -> button action that called this code, the app just hung. That was without any delay. So I don't know if this is working properly.

Comment: If it hung that means that something in your playSingleBall is hanging the code/not updating. Or you didn't reset the blocker properly

Comment: Without more context i'm afraid there isn't much else i can guide you with

Comment: Fair enough murphguy. I appreciate you trying to help me out.